# get frequency of a clock device in Linux

Tags: linux, clock

I am trying to adjust the frequency of a hardware clock device "dev/ptp0" in order to sync two clocks in Precision-Time-Protocol (PTP) Implementation, but the frequency doesn't seem to be adjusted synchronously as if some adjust calls are accumulated before being applied in the kernel and that is affecting my PI controller.

I want to confirm the system response to my frequency adjustments, so is there a way to get the current frequency of a clock in Linux?

I am using the following code to adjust/get frequency offsets but I want to get the actual frequency at the moment.

```
bool adjustFrequency(double adj)
{   
    struct timex tmx;
    memset(&tmx, 0, sizeof(tmx));
    tmx.modes = ADJ_FREQUENCY;

    tmx.freq = (long)(round(adj * 65.536));
    printf("setFrequency to  %lld %f\n", tmx.freq,  adj);

    if(clock_adjtime(clockId, &tmx) < 0) {
        printf("Could not adjust frequency offset of clock\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE
}

double getFrequency(void)
{
    struct timex tmx;
    memset(&tmx, 0, sizeof(tmx));
    if(clock_adjtime(clockId, &tmx) < 0) {
        printf("Could not get frequency of clock\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("getFrequency  %lld  %f\n",tmx.freq, (tmx.freq + 0.0) / 65.536 );
    return( (tmx.freq + 0.0) / 65.536);
}
```

Comment: See `man adjtime` for a description of the gradual adjustment to the system clock.  Sudden jumps cause problems.

Comment: I am not adjusting the system clock, I have a dedicated hardware clock for PTP for example "/dev/ptp0".

Comment: The system clock can measure frequency because that is built into the CPU.  There is no separate means of measuring frequency than what the hardware provides.  Only you would know the characteristics of your clock.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean  by "Only you would know the characteristics of your clock", I was thinking may be Linux provides a system like an ioctl call to the driver to get the current frequency of the device or something similar.

Comment: "the actual frequency at the moment" makes only limited sense. A frequency is the number of events per time. And a "moment" is something without a temporal extend. So the "frequency at the moment" is a division by zero.

Comment: @ceving clock frequency is the number of ticks per second in Hz right? I want to know how many ticks/second are we supposed to make, just to be sure that my frequency adjustments are applied synchronously with 'clock_adjtime' function call